# como passar parâmetro Url via get

Tags: htaccess, url, parâmetros, get

Estou tendo uma dúvida em relação a passar parâmetros de uma página para outra. Já tentei fazer de várias maneiras via get. Até consigo pegar o parâmetro, mas não são todos os parâmetros que consigo pegar. No exemplo abaixo, só consigo pegar o último id cadastrado na tabela...

Por exemplo:

Através de select, estou listando em forma de menu, no qual passo a variável id da tabela do banco de dados. Quando clico no link ele me redireciona para página que eu determinei, no entanto, só pega o último id cadastrado na tabela, mesmo apresentando uma url diferente, ele não pega os dados do id referente a este...

O código que eu estou usando é o seguinte:

```
prepare('SELECT id, categoria FROM teste ORDER BY categoria ASC');
$stmt->execute(); 
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
{ 
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    { 
        extract($row); $Link = "".$row['categoria'].""; ?>
".$Link.""?>
```

A outra página: "pagina"

```
prepare('SELECT * FROM teste WHERE id=" . $_GET["id"]');
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)  
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ // Escreve dados da pessoa } ?>
```

está desse jeito.

Como disse no início, só consigo pegar e visualizar os dados do último id cadastrado na tabela. Onde está o erro?

Alguém pode me ajudar com exemplos práticos?

Obs.: Estou trabalhando o sistema com pdo. Desde, já agradeço a todos que de alguma maneira puder me ajudar a resolver essa questão. o htaccess está configurado assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Já tentei outras configurações no `htaccess`, mas o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Sim. Resolvi fazer alterações.

Para chamar a outra página, coloquei assim também:

```
<a href="detalhe.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?><?php echo $id; ?></a>
```

Mas não resolveu o problema. Os dados são passados pela url, mas só pegar apenas um id, no caso o último cadastrado na tabela.

E na página que receberá os dados deixei assim:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id:$_GET["id"]');

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)


    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        // Escreve dados da pessoa

    }


?>
```

...

O erro continua.

Até agora não consegui resolver o problema.

Obs.: Posso passar os códigos das duas páginas se você quiser, para ver se consegue ver onde está o erro.

Comment: Ok, pode colocar. Tanto eu quanto os demais podemos dar uma olhada

Comment: Por favor mostre o código das páginas, parecem existir alguns erros de sintaxe.